# Name for region between two parallel planes

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there an established name for the region between two parallel planes? I can use sheet, layer, lamina... but I'd like to know whether there is an established name for it.

Comment: According to the help center I have to "*clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking*."

I think that the "*region between two parallel planes*" is not a hard concept to grasp, at least in this forum.

And I guess such concept must have a name.

What's wrong about asking "*Is there an established name for the region between two parallel planes?*" Is my English that bad?

Comment: To prevent this question from being closed a second time, you should be more precise about what you mean by parallel planes. Are you looking for terms in synthetic geometry (where points, lines, angles, curves and surfaces are all irreducible primitives)? Or are you looking for terms in analytic geometry (interpreting everything in terms of euclidean space)?

Comment: The question was nicely answered long ago, but your comment piques my curiosity to know the name in each of the cases you mention.

Comment: Well, that's good then. I didn't actually realize your question was an old one but came here because of the close/reopen votes. In any case, thanks for replying!

Comment: I guess I should say that I don't think there is a term for it in synthetic geometry, since usually we phrase things in terms of the points and curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *slab*. For example, [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), Exercise 2.12(a):

> A *slab* [is] a set of the form $\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \alpha \le a^T x \le \beta\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link.
It seems there are others who don't understand what "a region between two parallel planes" is.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been closed. I have voted to reopen it.